# How to get Android/IOS app to work together

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I was looking at Parse and Firebase and decided to go with Firebase and I recently just got into app development and want to work on some projects to learn more. One question I have is if I created an Android app and an iOS App that were used for the same exact purpose. So for example, I'd have a user sign up and register inside of the app on an Android device which would then take them to the dashboard. If I were to use Firebase and logged in with the same account from that Android device would I be able to login the iOS device with all the same information and all the data stored into that dashboard for that user?

Thank you so much and sorry if this sounds dumb! Just trying to learn.

Comment: Look at the Login section here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/08/build-better-mobile-apps-with-firebaseui_78.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication accounts are shared between all apps within in a single Firebase project. So if you log in on iOS with the same credentials as you used on Android (or vice versa, or with web involved) you will end up with the same user account.

Comment: Thank you so much!